# Stata using xtreg for cluster random effects models

Tags: stata, random-effects

I want to use xtreg to get the random effects intercepts for individual groups and their predicted values. However, all of the predict commands are just populating all of the groups with the constant value.

Using 1 year of data:

```
xtset group // set panel
xtreg outcome, re
predict u
predict xb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly a statistics question. The `xt` context here makes no difference to a standard feature of regression: if no predictors are specified, then the prediction returned is necessarily constant and equal to the mean response. We can't see your data, but the principle is universal. Here is a reproducible example:

```
. webuse grunfeld

. xtset
       panel variable:  company (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  year, 1935 to 1954
                delta:  1 year

. xtreg mvalue

Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =        200
Group variable: company                         Number of groups  =         10

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.0000                                         min =         20
     between = 0.0000                                         avg =       20.0
     overall = 0.0000                                         max =         20

                                                Wald chi2(0)      =          .
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2       =          .

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      mvalue |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   1081.681   422.1377     2.56   0.010     254.3064    1909.056
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  1332.6401
     sigma_e |  348.51426
         rho |  .93598465   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict predict
(option xb assumed; fitted values)

. su predict

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
     predict |        200    1081.681           0   1081.681   1081.681

. su mvalue

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      mvalue |        200    1081.681     1314.47      58.12     6241.7
```

Note that the names you use (examples in your case `xb` and `u`) have no implications for what is produced by `predict`. The default of `predict` in either case, with no predictors specified, is the predicted mean outcome.

You should check out the options of `predict` in this case, such as

```
predict u, u
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The u is the same within each group (varies across groups), but xb is still being populated with the overall constant across all observations. I would like to get the individual random effects for each group -- are you saying that this is not possible statistically? Is there also a way to run models for each year individually? I am getting an insufficient observations error.

Comment: If you check my example, then `u` differs by panel. We can't check your example at all.  I've already explained that `xb` is necessarily constant for what you did. You're also asking a new question in a comment; you should post a new question, show your code and give a reproducible example. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve